# Django Apache FastCGI restart

Tags: django, apache, fastcgi, restart

According to Django docs Django can be configured with FastCGI.

Here's our setup (note that I don't control Apache setup at my workplace and I'm required to use FastCGI since we already have it, rather than install WSGI):

The fcgi-relevant part of our apache conf is:

```
LoadModule fastcgi_module modules/mod_fastcgi.so

# IPC directory location
#
FastCgiIpcDir "/path/to/FastCGI_IPC"

# General CGI config
#
FCGIConfig -idle-timeout 30 -listen-queue-depth 4 -maxProcesses 40 -minProcesses 10 -maxClassProcesses 2 -killInterval 60 -updateInterval 20 -singleThreshhold 0 -multiThreshhold 10 -processSlack 5 -failed-restart-delay 10

# To use FastCGI scripts:
#
AddHandler fastcgi-script .fcg .fcgi .fpl

FastCgiServer "/path/to/my/django.fcgi" -listen-queue-depth 24 -processes 8 -restart-delay 1 -min-server-life 2 -failed-restart-delay 10
```

The last line should be most relevant.  My django.fcgi is:

```
#!/path/to/python-2.5/bin/python
import sys, os

open('pid', "w").write("%d" % (os.getpid()))

# Add a custom Python path.
sys.path.insert(0, "/path/to/django/")
sys.path.insert(0, "/path/to/python2.5/site-packages/")

# Switch to the directory of your project. (Optional.)
os.chdir("/path/to/django/site")

# Set the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable.
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "site.settings"

from django.core.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi
runfastcgi(method="threaded", daemonize="false")
```

According to

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/fastcgi/#restarting-the-spawned-server

restarting the fcgi should be as simple as

```
touch django.fcgi
```

but for us it doesn't result in a restart (which is why I'm writing the pid's to files).

Why doesn't the touch django.fcgi work?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, but I can propose an alternate solution that doesn't involve installing anything:

Just run django on some arbitrary localhost port (say 50000), and then do this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost:50000/$1 [P]
```

All it requires are the standard mod_rewrite and mod_proxy.

Comment: That may be OK for development but it's not suitable for production.  Django server processes only one request at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, an actual answer to your question, then. :)

Looks like you're missing an option.

> **-autoUpdate (none)**
>
> Causes mod_fastcgi to check the modification time of the application
> on disk before processing each request. If the application on disk has been changed, the process manager is notified and all running instances of the application are killed off. In general, it's preferred that this type of functionality be built-in to the application (e.g. every 100th request it checks to see if there's a newer version on disk and exits if so). There may be an outstanding problem (bug) when this option is used with -restart.

-- http://www.fastcgi.com/mod_fastcgi/docs/mod_fastcgi.html#FastCgiConfig

Comment: Thanks, but I'm somewhat skeptical that this is *the* answer.  How exactly does this killing happen?  Is it graceful?  Does it wait for any on-going requests to be fully satisfied (i.e. wait for the response).

Comment: It sounds like it isn't very graceful at all. But it does explain what you have to do get the 'touch django.fcgi' to restart your app. I didn't design it, I was just answering your question. Like I said in the other answer, my opinion is that you're better off running django through the python wsgi server of your choice and just using mod_proxy. But you don't seem to want to actually try anything, so... Best of luck?